# Firefox scrolls up and down when I press the arrows

Tags: firefox

When I push down the arrow key in my keyboard, Firefox scrolls site to its bottom. How can I configure Firefox to scroll smoothly, so that I can see couple of new lines as I press the key? I have Firefox 25.0 and Ubuntu 13.10. I tried to reinstall Firefox and in preferences I chose smooth auto scrolling. It looks like there is a cursor in the WWW-site I'm watching and by pressing keys the cursor jump between different links.

Comment: Does this only happen in Firefox, or elsewhere on your system also?

Comment: At least this does not happen in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caret Browsing is provided as a way to navigate through a web page by using only the keyboard.

You may have Caret Browsing turned on.  You can press press <kbd>F7</kbd> to toggle caret browsing on/off, and see if it works.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)